# Apache POI 3.9 Word jars is Working for JBOSS 4.2.2GA but not working for JBOSS 6.0.0 Final

Tags: java, jboss, apache-poi

I am developing Word document using apache poi 3.9. I have used the jars from apache poi binary distribution 3.9.
I have used the below Apache 3.9 jars.

1. poi-3.9-20121203
2. poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203
3. poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9
4. poi-scratchpad-3.9
5. xmlbeans-2.3.0

when i am working with JBOSS 4.2.2 GA it is working Fine with out issues. when i am working with JBOSS 6.0.0 Final The following Exception occuring.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/POIXMLTypeLoader
    org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:292)
    org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:167)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:413)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:225)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1858)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:459)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.jboss.remotehostfilter.RemoteHostFilter.doFilter(RemoteHostFilter.java:90)
```

Please provide some suggessions. how we can work with JBOSS 6.0.0 Final.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apache POI 3.9 is ancient! The dates in the filenames show you it's over 5 years old! Why are you using such an old version, and what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: I'd agree with Gagravarr - I'd suggest using the latest poi jars and then tweaking your code if need be.  I needed to do it myself to use there PDF Writer/Reader and I only had to touch a couple (maybe three) lines of code